# AndroidRuntime::getJNIEnv() returns NULL

Tags: android

I have the below code snippet in my the JNI part:

```
JNIEnv* env = AndroidRuntime::getJNIEnv();
```

The above statement always returns NULL in my function. Then I use env and call some method in Java code using callback mechanism.

It's this part of the code in getJNIEnv() that always returns NULL.

```
if (vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK)
{
        return NULL;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with code? It looks pretty normal to me since other functions in JNI too have almost similar implementation.

Answer (score 8):

First, don't use `AndroidRuntime::getJNIEnv()`.  That's not part of the NDK API.  You should be using the JNI `GetEnv` function instead.

Second, `GetEnv` returns NULL if the current thread is not attached to the VM.  (Remember, `JNIEnv` is thread-specific.)  If you created the thread yourself, you will need to use the JNI `AttachCurrentThread` function to attach it.

Both of these require a `JavaVM` pointer.  There's only one of these per process, so you can get it during `JNI_OnLoad` or a setup call from your program (`GetJavaVM` function) when you have a `JNIEnv` passed in.

If you haven't yet, read through the [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) page (which includes references to some comprehensive JNI docs).